# SharePoint 2013 learning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Want to update our team with SharePoint 2013. Can you pl guide on these:

1. what are the major areas apart from apps we should learn initially.
2. where can I get info on major changes in 2013?
3. Pl send link having precise material which will guide to start solid learning on 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried google it? "differences between sharepoint 2010 and 2013" comes up with tons of resources regarding at least point 2, and thereby 1,3 to

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to SP, so I've been looking at videos and reading.  I can recommend these links.

Microsoft has a set of videos on SP 2013:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/apps/fp123626

There is a "what's new" video on you tube from a training company:
http://youtu.be/BlrY9P_7OXs

Pluralsight ($) has many hours of teaching videos on SP 2013.  There are many books and MS has several information dense sites.  Its pretty easy to find information about Sharepoint.